# Send email with column values before and after change with workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-workflow

I am trying to send an email to specified users when a column in a list changes in MOSS 2007 with workflow. I have a comments column in a list and whenever any user updates that comment, a mail should go to the creator and specific group stating what has changed.

I saw a response which states to create 2 lists and keep them in sync and compare values of comments from the two lists. But that is not a perfect solution.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution would be this:

- let say you have cells named

```
       *first* *second* *third* *fourth*
```

- then you make (in same list) cells with same structure only name them like this

```
       *first2* *second2* *third2* *fourth2*
```

- Then you create the workflow that send user cell values, where content between cell and cell2 is not same. For instance

```
       check if *first* and *first2* are same, if not, add to message value of *first*.
       ... repeat for all four of them
```

- then copy the value from cell to cell2 (this will give you history)

```
       from *first* to *first2*
       from *second* to *second2*
              .
              .
```

Hope it helps. Cheers

Comment: This is some what the same solution already provided. Rather than different lists, you are using same list to copy columns values.

Comment: Well you said it's too much work with 2 lists - in compare to that: this solution is shorter for sure!
I'm sorry but there is no plug&play solution I could provide.
Please post back if you find a shorter one- I would be very interested to see one.